# binding parameters into sql query in eclipse.persistence.logging

Tags: sql, eclipse, logging, parameters, bind

I am using eclipse.persistence.logging to log SQL queries. I want to bind the parameters into the query on the right place where they belong, so I could just copy+paste from log file into database development environment and run that query. For example I want "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 5" instead of "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? bind => [5]" to be logged.

In the *persistance.xml* I have these properties already:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value=my cutom logger class/>
```

And I made a custom logger class to override method *public void log(SessionLogEntry logEntry)*, where I am replacing the '?' with parameters from the 'bind => [...]' part of the message using regex and string functions. 
It all works fine but I have one problem, which I don't know how to solve. 
Parameters in the '[...]' are separated by comma, so when I split the '[...]' part by commas to get an array of parameters, the string/varchar parameters containing commas mess up the whole thing and are splitted into multiple parts by those commas. The parameters are not quoted to mark the start and the end of the string/varchar parameter, so I don't see any solution to prevent the splitting. 
At first I thought the parameters for the message would be accesible by *getParameters()* method of *SessionLogEntry* class and easier to handle, but this method returns *null* and the parameters are only in the message, therefore I used the regex and string functions.

Can anyone help me with this? Is there any other way to achieve the result?